# Indexing mysql database using elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, apache, elasticsearch, lucene

I wish to integrate Elastic Search for my existing mysql database.So I want to index the dB.How shall I do this ? I didn’t get sufficient help from google.please help me

Comment: Can you provide some additional detail on what you've tried, what didn't work, why it didn't work, etc? When I [Google "mysql to elasticsearch"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+to+elasticsearch&oq=mysql+to+elast&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62l2.2645j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I get scores of quality information.

Comment: @MatthewBoynes: I followed this tutorial https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart and at last im getting following error: "error" : "IndexMissingException[[jdbc] missing]",
  "status" : 404

Answer (score 1):

If you're still stuck on this:

Are you sure you executed the 3rd step of the [QuickStart](http://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart) ?

```
./bin/plugin --url http://bit.ly/10FJhEd -install river-jdbc
```

It installs the jdbc-river plugin and creates the jdbc index, which should fix the encountered error:

```
"error" : "IndexMissingException[[jdbc] missing]", "status" : 404
```